# Real integral giving a complex result

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gaussian-integral

I have to solve the following integral

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^x-1}{x} e^{-\frac{(x+y)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$$

This integral converges, becaue $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ goes to 1 for $x \to 0$.
When I feed the previous integral to Mathematica, however, I get logarithms with negative arguments.
For the case $y=0$, for example, the result of the integral is $-i \pi$.
How can I have a complex argument from such a real integral? Is mathematica doing something wrong?

Comment: If you have two or more logarithms with negative arguments, maybe you can combine them [$\log x + \log y = \log(xy)$] to get logarithms of positive arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica is very wrong.  If you use NIntegrate, it gets itself right.  I am not sure why this is happening yet, but I can direct you toward the right answer for the simple case $y=0$ and $2 \sigma^2=1$.

Note that

$$\frac{e^x-1}{x} = \int_0^1 dt \, e^{x t} $$

Then the integral we want is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, e^{-x^2} \, \int_0^1 dt \, e^{x t} $$

We can reverse the order of integration and complete the square the exponential to get

$$\int_0^1 dt \, e^{t^2/4} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, e^{-(x-t/2)^2}  = \pi \operatorname{erfi}{\left (\frac12 \right )}$$

which agrees with the numerical results in Mathematica.

Comment: This is really interesting to know. Cheers :-)

Comment: I will send in a report to Wolfram and see what they find.  Then again, I found this with v. 9, and maybe they fixed this in the latest version.